# How can I force my phone to connect to US-based cell towers only?

Tags: android-10, samsung-galaxy-s-9

I use a Samsung Galaxy S9 with Android 10, and plan to enter Mexico from the US via the land border. How can I force my phone to connect to US-based [cell towers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_site) only? (I believe my data usage will get way more expensive for non-US data use)

Comment: Most phones have the ability to turn off roaming, for example in a Pixel 3A it is in Settings, Network & Internet, Mobile Network, and toggle Roaming off... Otherwise contact your carrier and see, in some cases roaming into Mexico is included in your plan or they may have a cost-effective add-on for roaming into Mexico.

Comment: @acejavelin thanks I'd like to keep roaming if still able to connect to a US-based cell tower

Comment: Most US carriers have roaming agreements with Mexican and other Central and Latin America carriers, I would suggest reaching out to your carrier, otherwise be aware that roaming is roaming and could result in very high fees. Best to just turn mobile data off except when absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It is currently impossible to do force one's phone to connect to US-based cell towers only. E.g. from [Dicknose22](https://www.reddit.com/user/Dicknose22) on https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/j5ntyg/how_can_i_force_my_phone_to_connect_to_usbased/g7tefwh/:

> Not to the best of my knowledge, even with total root access, your phone and the tower communicate on what to connect to you do not have power to override what your carrier decides you should connect to.